# Read Karate config from YAML

Tags: karate

I would like to define environment-specific properties in a `.yml`/`.yaml` file. Therefore I created the following `test.yaml`:

```
baseUrl:  'http://localhost:1234'
```

Next, I wrote this `karate-config.js`:

```
function() {
  var env = karate.env;
   if (!env) {
     env = 'test'; // default is test
   }
   // config =  read(env + '.yaml')
   var config = read('/home/user/git/karate-poc/src/test/java/test.yaml');
   // var config = read('test.yaml');
   // var config = read('classpath:test.yaml');
  return config;
}
```

As seen here https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files the `read()` function should be known by Karate, however I'm not sure if this only applies to `.feature` files or the `karate-config.js` too.

Unfortunately, none of the above `read()`s work, as I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: javascript function call failed: could not find or read file: /home/user/git/karate-poc/src/test/java/test.yaml, prefix: NONE
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFunctionCall(Script.java:1602)
```

I'm sure that the file exists and is readable.

Am I doing something wrong or is my approach not supported? If it's not supported, what would be the recommended way to read the configuration based on the environment from a YAML file (once) in order to use it in (multiple) `.feature` files?

Thank you very much

Edit: Tree structure of the project:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── src
    └── test
        └── java
            ├── karate
            │   └── rest
            │       ├── rest.feature
            │       └── RestRunner.java
            ├── karate-config.js
            └── test.yaml
```

Run with `./gradlew test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JS, use the `karate` object, which is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object

So this should work:

```
var config = karate.read('classpath:test.yaml');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter. I use `config =  karate.read('classpath:' + env + '.yaml')` now and it works exactly as expected. I am thankful and admire your work for Karate.