# Read Karate config from optional YAML file - is there a check if a file exists?

Tags: yaml, config, karate, environment

In a similar use case as in [Read Karate config from YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49445592/6221202) I want to read my environment config for Karate from a YAML file. This works well with `karate.read`. My extended use case now would be the following:

- read environment config of common environments from a YAML file which is in version control
- have a file with custom environments not in version control and read from that file too
- for all environments (based on a ID field) that are defined in both files the custom environment definition overwrites the common one

I now have to read two files but for the file with the custom environments I don't know if it will exist because the user might choose to not have any custom environments defined. Is there a way to check if the second file exists before attempting to read it? I have checked the documentation for the `karate` object but have not found anything like that.

If that wouldn't be possible, is there another way how my use case could be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karate has a built-in way to use dev-env specifc config that may not exist: https://github.com/intuit/karate#environment-specific-config

That said, note that you can catch exceptions in JS, so that gives you some more options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554175/143475

```
try {
  // read
} catch(e) {
  // print e if needed and ignore
}
```