# Karate - org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException Exception observed in screenshot method

Tags: testing, karate

I am getting an error while running my tests on Jenkins and using screenshots in Karate.

My tests are passing locally, but fail intermittently when executed through Jenkins. I am using Karate 1.2.0

The error observed is:

```
js failed:
>>>>
01: screenshot()
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:895)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.screenshot(DevToolsDriver.java:858)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.Driver.screenshot(Driver.java:120)
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies related to karate -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please start trying 1.3.0.RC1. Details here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.3.0-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: I used 1.3.0.RC1 in my tests now, but the issue still exists. Can you help further?

Comment: @sonal I've tried to fix it here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2087 - so if you can follow the develop guide or somehow validate, that will be great. for the time being, try using a `try { } catch` around the `screenshot()` refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67024149/143475 and you can use the `eval` keyword